# How to map formatted Datetime value in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a datetime issue between SQL Server and a C# (ASP.NET Core Web API) model.

Here is my model:

```
    public string Text { get; set; }   
    public int StatusId { get; set; }    
    public  DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
```

Here is my SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    StatusId, 
    (FORMAT(DS.CreatedAt, 'dd/MM/yyyy - hh:mm:ss')) AS CreatedAt,     
    DS.CreatedBy, S.[Text] 
FROM
    [Inspection].[Dossier_Status] DS 
INNER JOIN 
    [DT_Inspection].[Status] S ON S.Id = StatusId 
WHERE 
    DossierId = 'efb8702d-15cc-4503-8198-1dbca3f28bc6' 
ORDER BY 
    DS.CreatedAt DESC
```

After this query runs in a controller, the `CreatedAt` property will have a value like this:

```
0001-01-01T00:00:00
```

but we should have

```
06/09/2021 - 12:00:02
```

Finally, the method that does the job in controller,

```
string Sql = "SELECT StatusId, (FORMAT(DS.CreatedAt, 'dd/MM/yyyy - hh:mm:ss')), DS.CreatedBy, S.[Text] " +
                    " FROM[Inspection].[Dossier_Status] DS " +
                    "INNER JOIN [DT_Inspection].[Status] S ON S.Id = StatusId " +
                    "WHERE DossierId = '" + DossierId + "' " +
                    "ORDER BY DS.CreatedAt DESC";

using var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled);

await using var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
var result = await sqlConnection.QueryAsync<Dossier_StatusVUE>(Sql);
```

How can I get returned SQL property `CreatedAt` in the desired format?

Comment: Why return a formatted date  `nvarchar` at all? Leave it as a strongly typed date (and time) data type and worry about the format in the presentation layer.

Comment: Your model has a DateTime property and I assume that DS.CreatedAt in your database has datetime type too. Why are you asking the sql server to format that value? Simply load it into your model and format it where you need it. If you still want to use sql server for this task then replace the type of CreatedAt prop in your model with string,

Comment: Obligatory comment to state to **fix** your major security flaw due to SQL Injection.

Comment: @Larnu Good catch. I completely missed there was a value concatenated in there. I updated my answer based on what I infer is the right parameter mechanism for his situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**There is no such thing as a "formatted datetime".** If you format a DateTime value, *it isn't a DateTime anymore;* it's just a string. Typically, you should return a plain (no format) DateTime value back from the database into the model, and let the view handle any formatting needs. This is true even for Web API scenarios, where the View might just be JSON.

So in the question, you see the bad value because the Model is expecting a `DateTime`, but we supplied a string, and it failed to parse it. We can fix this by removing the `FORMAT` call from the SQL, and letting it return an actual DateTime, like this:

```
string Sql = "SELECT StatusId, DS.CreatedAt, DS.CreatedBy, S.[Text] " +
              " FROM[Inspection].[Dossier_Status] DS " +
              "INNER JOIN [DT_Inspection].[Status] S ON S.Id = StatusId " +
              "WHERE DossierId = @Dossier_ID " +
              "ORDER BY DS.CreatedAt DESC";

using var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled);
await using var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));

var result = await sqlConnection.QueryAsync<Dossier_StatusVUE>(Sql, new {Dossier_ID = DossierID});
```

Now the correct value should get into the `result` variable, and we fixed the nasty sql injection issue at the same time.

However, this is only *half* the fix. The next step is updating the view to know how to present this DateTime value. However, we don't have enough information on how the View is constructed, so I'll have to leave that part to you.